# Kafka Stream state store data is not getting Deleted

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Using Kafka State store (Rock DB) in low level processor API with custom key.

Now trying to delete the KvStore  and flush after that. Still it is available when in next punctuate  is getting called .

Why Not is is delete the data from Rock DB ?

KeyValueStore kvStore

kvStore.delete(CustomKey)

Comment: String Key is must?

Comment: This should actually work. Maybe you can share your code?